# Cant write/read to/from external storage with LibGDX

Tags: android, libgdx, filesystem

My `create` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.external("file.txt");
    file.writeString("My god, it's full of stars", false);
}
```

I allso included:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

The Exception i get is this:

```
02-13 14:45:51.858 12439-12466/com.snowdevs.tweetiebirds E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1120
Process: com.snowdevs.tweetiebirds, PID: 12439
com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error writing file: file.txt (External)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writeString(FileHandle.java:353)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writeString(FileHandle.java:339)
   at com.snowdevs.tweetiebirds.TweetieBirdsGame.create(TweetieBirdsGame.java:22)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:254)
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1519)
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error writing file: file.txt (External)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writer(FileHandle.java:330)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writeString(FileHandle.java:350)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writeString(FileHandle.java:339) 
   at com.snowdevs.tweetiebirds.TweetieBirdsGame.create(TweetieBirdsGame.java:22) 
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:254) 
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1519) 
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240) 
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/file.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writer(FileHandle.java:322)
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writeString(FileHandle.java:350) 
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writeString(FileHandle.java:339) 
   at com.snowdevs.tweetiebirds.TweetieBirdsGame.create(TweetieBirdsGame.java:22) 
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:254) 
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1519) 
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240) 
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
   at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
   at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:87) 
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writer(FileHandle.java:322) 
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writeString(FileHandle.java:350) 
   at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writeString(FileHandle.java:339) 
   at com.snowdevs.tweetiebirds.TweetieBirdsGame.create(TweetieBirdsGame.java:22) 
   at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:254) 
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1519) 
   at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
```

I use a Nexus 5 with Android 6 Marshmallow for testing. 
I searched and found that Android 6 uses runtime permissions but the LibGDX guys says that it works even on Android 6... Is there a fix With or Without runtime permissions?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is a cross-post from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35380746/cant-write-nor-read-to-from-external-storage-with-libgdx). Cross-posting is not allowed on StackExchange sites.

Comment: But thanks for coming back and marking it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is now answered in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44028465/2815687), and it goes like this:

I check if the user has granted permission of external storage and request permission if not granted by using:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
         this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, WRITE_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

All of this is android-specific code and thus resides in the `AndroidLauncher` class.

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing to the local area (Where the app is stored) then don't use the external file type. The correct type to use is `local` as the `local` type will store it in the same folder as the app. The problem with `external` is that `external` reads from the root directory onward. So on Windows the `external` path would need to specify the drive and other such specialized locations on the hard drive such as `C:/Windows/system32.sys` or `F:/Videos/Other/NotAdultVideo.mp4` whereas using the `local` format allows you to store it in the local area near to your app run-time and such.